# How to script SSIS SQL Agent Job Step to run on localhost?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've created a SQL Agent Job that executes a SSIS package as one of the job steps.  I'm trying to get configure the SSIS job step to be set to execute the package on "localhost" (or whatever I need to call it to reference the same SQL server instance the job is on) so that I can script it the job out, and deploy between environments using the same script.

This is SQL Server 2012, so I'm trying to run it using the SSIS Catalog that's installed on the local SQL instance.  I don't want to have to go into the script and change server names as we push the script from development, to the test environment, and eventually production.

I've tried putting "localhost" in the "Server" textbox, then clicking the "..." by the "Package" setting, but I get an error saying "Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections" -- which I take to mean that it's attempting to connect to a server that is actually named localhost, as opposed to just checking itself.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: try dot symbol instead of localhost, or just this (local).

Comment: Borat Sagdiyev - Good thoughts, but those also produce the same result.

Comment: Can we see what the actual script to call the package from the Agent job looks like currently?

Comment: @Cortright - Strange. dot symbol works for me on SSIS 2008. This is a sample connection string i lifted off a connection manager - Data Source=.;User ID=luser;Initial Catalog=Stacks;Persist Security Info=True;Application Name=SSIS-Pkg-{big code here}LocalHost.Stacks.luser;

Comment: Borat -- inside a connection string is fine, this is within the SSIS "type" of SQL Agent job step, using SSIS Catalog (which I believe is a new thing in 2012).

Comment: @Cortright - Did you enable the package configuration on your SSIS pacakge. It might one of the few reasons to work on different environmetns.

Answer (score -1):

How about in your script:

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\....dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"' + @@SERVERNAME + '\"" ...'
```

And then pass it (`@command = @Command`) to `sp_add_jobstep` instead.

You might have to handle non-default instances returned by `@@SERVERNAME` special because SSIS doesn't use the instance name, I guess, but I didn't try it out.